# How to keep fetching 2 documents in Cloud firestore on a button click?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my database:

[image]

I want to keep fetching 2 document in the list on click of a button, I tried this code, but it didn't work. Like on

1st click, fetch `doc_0` and `doc_1`,

2nd click, fetch `doc_2` and `doc_3`, so forth and so on.

```
class _FetchState extends State<Fetch> {
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> _list = [];
  DocumentSnapshot _lastDoc;

  void _fetch() async {
    Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
        .limit(2)
        .startAtDocument(_lastDoc)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
          _list.addAll(snapshot.documents);
          _lastDoc = _list.last;
          print("length = ${_list.length}");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _fetch),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wat are u getting now?

Comment: @ PeterHaddad At first it wont' run because I am passing `null` to `startAtDocument`, after that it says I need to provide `orderBy` which I don't understand why.

Comment: If you want to get the document like that it must be ordered by a field inside your doc, like timestamp or name or sth. Can you specify in which field you want to order your docs?

Comment: otherwise it would be getting random docs everytime without order, might put the doc you queried in 2nd index in the 5th because it wasn't ordered.

Comment: @Henok Thanks for your comment, as you said it must be ordered by a field, does it mean I must have same fields in all my document? Because currently none of them share the same `key`.

Comment: not particularly all of them, just the ones under the same collection. If you want to solve this just add one same key it could be a string which sets random values that later can be used to order alphabetically or timestamp to order by date any one of your preferences. Additionally Some how I feel like the docs must have shared the same structure because how is it possible for you to access data in 100 different structures anyway if you are accessing them in a ' if else' statement ok you can parse it in 100 different ways but you're accessing them inside a loop.

Comment: I'm answering your question like this because its a matter  of decision and not mostly coding and I'm not sure if it satisfies you. If you think it solved you're problem let me know I'll post a brief summary in the answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: @Henok Thanks for giving me idea, someone already posted the answer, I didn't try it yet, you can also write down your valuable comments in answer, I'll surely upvote yours.

Comment: you're very welcome, it's you're decision which solution is easy to implement and which works for you I'll post this one and try his solution first andb and mine. thanks !

Comment: Something I think is kinda missed in the rest of this post is that the Firebase console UI sorts your data collection, but your data is not ordered in anyway. If you add a new document to the collection with the key "aDoc_1" it will be at the top (in the console ui). Therefore to do pagination, your data needs to be queried and sorted (orderedBy) like Henok suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could be solved with only two very simple steps without changing much of your code,

1. Add a field to your doc to sort items with( a string, int or a timestamp).
2. Then in your own code just add orderBy(yourValue).

Thats it !

Comment: Thank you, my code actually won't work in first place, because i am passing `null` when it runs for the first time. I upvoted yours for your suggestion, and will give a try to aldobaie answer and if that works, I'll accept his.

Comment: I gave it a try and finally able to solve it, aldobaie solution only provided solution with first time work which I already know, the real solution to the problem was adding some sort of same field like a timestamp as you suggested. So, your solution is 80% complete and his 20%, so think I should accept yours.

Comment: any new progress? if you encountered issues implementing it let me know, we can also work on the remaining 20% of my solutionl.

Comment: Hi, actually it worked when I messaged you earlier today, everything is up and running fine without any issues, I am still debugging to see how many calls it would make to read the document, if you can post a good solution regarding good way to listen and close things in my current code, I'll be thankful.

Comment: I asked you because you said it worked and you haven't accepted it, the best practices on closing the listener is out of the scope of this question, post another question about it and I will be happy to participate.

Comment: Just because the other answerer posted more code detail along with info, I awarded him bounty but accepted yours.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called Firestore Pagination in Flutter. 
Basically you need to call the first page without the `startAtDocument` once, then save the `last_document_reference`, then start using `startAtDocument` fore all other pages with updating the `last_document_reference`. [You can see an example here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2)

**EDIT:** Here is part of your code modified to what you need:

```
void _fetch() async {
  if(_lastDoc == null) {
    Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
        .orderBy("name") //you can change the key "name" to whatever field key you have
        .limit(2)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
          _list.addAll(snapshot.documents);
          _lastDoc = _list.last;
          print("length = ${_list.length}");
    });
  }
  else {
    Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
        .orderBy("name") //you can change the key "name" to whatever field key you have
        .startAtDocument(_lastDoc)
        .limit(2)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
          _list.addAll(snapshot.documents);
          _lastDoc = _list.last;
          print("length = ${_list.length}");
    });
  }
}
```

**Note 1:** You have to manage those listeners! With every call you'll be creating new listeners which you should some how manage. It's out of scope to talk about it here. And in case of documents being updated you have to manage the trigger accordingly.

**Note 2:** You should be using `setState((){ _list.addAll(snapshot.documents) });` to update the build (or use other means to do so).

**Edit 2:**
Thinking about it, you only need a listener on the new messages, but the old ones should be fixed data without any modifications (no edits or deletes); So here the second part without any listeners:

```
  else {
    Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
        .orderBy("name") //you can change the key "name" to whatever field key you have
        .startAtDocument(_lastDoc)
        .limit(2)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((snapshot) {
          _list.addAll(snapshot.documents);
          _lastDoc = _list.last;
          print("length = ${_list.length}");
    });
  }
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should be something like that.
Now you only have one listener which should update with the new documents. You might still need to handle the changes.

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_query, No order by clause specified, You need to order by at least one field when using {start/end}{At/After/Before}Document as you need some value to e.g. start after.)` Please update full solution so that I can accept it.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName I have updated the answer. And pointed some problems you might face.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName if you feel this answer fulfills your question, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to firestore documents and all. But just in case you would like to add some more code this might help.

Initialize a variable `button_clicks = 0;`

When the button is clicked, try to fetch the file with name `file_0` and then increasing the value of our variable, fetch the `file_1`.

Something like:

```
// on button click:
{
fetch_file('file_'+button_clicks);  //Function which fetches file_0.. The firestore instance code..
button_clicks++ ; //Increment in variable.
fetch_file('file_'+button_clicks);  //Function which fetches file_1
button_clicks++ ; //Increment in variable.
}
```

Now the next time you click the button , the same thing will start from `file_2` because your variable `button_clicks = 2`.

I would strongly suggest to store this value somewhere in `firebase-realtime-database` separate for each user or as per your needs if you want the user to download from `file_0` on app restart.

This logic should help. :-)